# Getting the type of method parameters in reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I work with reflection. And I need to get the parameter method of my set () entity to call the corresponding fill method in accordance with the type.

```
try{
            Class clazz = aClass.getClass();
            Object object = clazz.newInstance();
            while (clazz != Object.class){
                Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
                for (Method method : methods){
                    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ProductAnnotation.class)) {
                        Object[] strategyObj =  new Object[1];
                        if (method.getReturnType().getName().equals("int")) {              //reflexion never comes in if
                            strategyObj[0] = strategy.setInt(bundle.getString(method.getName().substring(3).toLowerCase()));
                            method.invoke(object, strategyObj);
                        }if (method.getParameterTypes().getClass().getTypeName().equals("String")){   //reflexion never comes in if
                            strategyObj[0] = strategy.setString(bundle.getString(method.getName().substring(3).toLowerCase()));
                            method.invoke(object, strategyObj);
                        }
                    }
                }
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            }
            return (FlyingMachine) object;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IOException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I tried to use `getReturnedType ()` and `getParametrTypes ()`, but the reflexion does not enter any condition. What was I wrong about?

My Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ProductAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

Methods that should cause reflection.Depending on the type of method, call one of these methods for further processing and filling in the data.

```
@Override
    public int setInt(String title) throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        checkValue = true;
        while (checkValue) {
            System.out.println(title + "-->");
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line.matches("\\d*")) {
                System.out.println(title + " = " + Integer.parseInt(line));
                checkValue = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong value, try again");
                checkValue = true;
            }
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(line);
    }

setString() works exactly the same scheme.
```

Comment: Is `ProductAnnotation` annotated itself with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` ?

Comment: Exactly: please show us a [mcve], containing the code that *fails* to work with the reflection part. Your whole code here checks for that annotation, are you sure it is present on the methods you want to inspect?!

Comment: All other parts of the code work well, the annotation provided. The problem is getting the type parameter of the method at the moment of reflection.

Comment: Again: show us example code that you *expect* to work with this reflection piece.

Comment: @VIRICH You would need to show the code which is calling the method ... and the method which contains the above snippet.

Answer (score 1):

`Method::getParameterTypes` returns `Class[]`.

So your code `method.getParameterTypes().getClass()` will always return `[Ljava.lang.Class`. try this code:

```
Class[] types = method.getParameterTypes();
if (types.length == 1 && types[0] == String.class) {
    // your second condition...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's helped me)